# My submitted app in Google Play Store is showing "Internal Testing" as the status. What is the next step to proceed with the app publish?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I've developed an app in reactnative and submitted my apps .abb bundle file to Google Play Store and filled all the necessary forms and passed the 12 steps which Google Play Store needed me to complete. Now after 1 week of the submission for review, the submitted app status is still is "Internal Testing". Does this mean I need to do do any additional testing from my side?

P.S. I've studied Google Play Store documentations and it's still vague to me.

Comment: How do you want to publish the app? to the public or to certain testers?